# Why isn't the bool member in struc not taking the user input?

Tags: c++, struct, boolean, user-input

I'm creating a function called struct Car, where it takes the user input (in int main) of a couple member values. One of the members is a bool (isElectric), but I can't seem to figure out why the program doesn't allow me to input anything else after I enter "true" or "false". Is there a reason why the output comes out failing?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Car {
  string color;
  string model;
  int year;
  bool isElectric;
  double topSpeed;
};


int main() {



Car car1;
cout << "Enter information for Car 1." << endl;
cout << "Car Color?: ";
cin >> car1.color;
cin.ignore();
cout << "Car Model?: ";
getline(cin, car1.model);
cout << "Car Year?: ";
cin >> car1.year;
cout << "Is the car electric?: ";
cin >> car1.isElectric;
```

**Console:**

```
Enter information for Car 1.
Car Color?: Yellow
Car Model?: Model  S
Car Year?: 2020
Is the car electric?: true
Car Top Speed?: Enter information for Car 2.
Car Color?: Car Model?: Car Year?: Is the car electric?: Car Top Speed
```

Comment: Try entering 1 and 0 for the boolean value and see what happens, this hopefully helps with understanding booleans

Answer (score 2):

The default way to input a `bool` value is the integers `0` (for false) or `1` (for true).

To input the string `"true"` you need to use the [`std::boolalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/boolalpha) manipulator:

```
cin >> boolalpha >> car1.isElectric;
```